# UITextField responder line is overlapping with border, How to position responder?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

[image]

Blue colored text positioning line is overlapping with border in UITextField. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Naveen.

Comment: Text fields *borderStyle* is *UITextBorderStyleNone*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a padding and add to the uitextfield as follows:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
yourtextfield.leftView = unpaddingView;
yourtextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Release the padding view

Comment: Your answer is working for me. Thanks dude :) I appreciate your effort.